# Decompress base64 zipstream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a plug-in which can transfer the zip file from web to asp.net mvc background and decompress it into my server.

In my website, i choose a zip file
`<input type="file" id="FileZip">`
and post it's value to my asp.net method

```
public async Task<string> FileTrs(string Zip)
```

Then i got the string of the following type

> data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,

How can i unzip it into my server ? 
Could anybody tell me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this and then use for example the [SharpZip-lib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) to decompress my file.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> FileTrs()
{
     if (Request.Files.Any)
     {
         var file = Request.Files[0];
         if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            // Unzip file here with for example SharpZipLib
         }
     }
 }
```

Examples for how to use SharpZip [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples)
Maybe you need to convert the uploaded file to a stream before using it in the SharpoZipLib.

Comment: you mean use the <form> ?

Comment: Yes, to post your file you have to have your `<input type="file" id="FileZip"` in a `<form>` tag so you can post it to the server. Are you using an alternative method?

Comment: i 'am finding the way to translate the base64 to gzip stream but failed. so i'am  confused whether this method can work

Comment: Not sure you need to convert it. With the solution above you get a file representation from `var file = Request.Files[0];` which have a method `InputStream` which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Framework 4.5 and higher!! This shall be applicable
Answers how to Unzip, If you have access to server, It shall not be an Issue.

```
    static void Extractor()
    { 
      string whereMyZIPFileIs = @"path\fileName.zip";
      string whereIWantToExtract = @"pathOfExtraction";
      System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(whereMyZIPFileIs, whereIWantToExtract);
    }
```

Please add "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" to Reference

Comment: the file is only in client-side, and in server-side i  don't know the path, i just know the base64 string.

Comment: @CeryDe What does Base64 String Represent when Decoded?

Comment: data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,